# WebView Timeout Issue while accessing an AD authenticated website

Tags: android, webview

I used a timeout boolean value setting 20 seconds after which the timeout should occur and the webview should stop loading the webpage. Here's the code:

**Web.java**

```
public class Web extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
final Activity activity = this;
public Uri imageUri;
Global ht;
boolean timeout = true;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 2888;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    myHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    ht = (Global) getApplicationContext();
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    final String url = "http://192.168.1.1";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);


    //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setFocusable(false);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    } else {

        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }

    int DELAY = 1000;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }, DELAY);

    /*Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    //Start this timer when you create you task
    myTimer.schedule(loaderTask, 3000); // 3000 is delay in millies*/

    // webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    // Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            // for downloading directly through download manager
            final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,
                    contentDisposition, mimetype);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
            intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });




    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }



        // The undocumented magic method override
        // Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Web.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressWarnings({"unused", "rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Web.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Android 4.1
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Web.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    Web.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

        // For Android 5.0+
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView,
                                         ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                                         WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            }
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });


}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
        //Your code to do
        try {
            webView.stopLoading();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }

        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Web.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Could not load content Due to bad connectivity or invalid credentials");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /*public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        try {
            webView.stopLoading();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }

        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Web.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Could not load content Due to bad connectivity or invalid credentials");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
        super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

    @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
        // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
        onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
    }*/
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gathering content, please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    if (timeout) {
                        // do what you want
                        try {
                            webView.stopLoading();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                        }
                        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Web.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Could not load content Due to bad connectivity or invalid credentials");
                        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                                startActivity(getIntent());
                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(Web.this, LoginActivity2.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            };
            myHandler.postDelayed(run, 20000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
        timeout = false;
    }

    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                          HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        handler.proceed("abc", "123");
        // To change body of overridden  methods  use File| Settings| File Templates.
    }
}



    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }

}
/*class loaderTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Times Up");
        if(isPageLoadedComplete){
        }
    }
    }*/}
```

But every time when I try inserting wrong credentials, the boolean value **"timeout"** gets setted to false instead of giving it true while the page starts loading. I have setted the boolean value to false only when the page is completely loaded(in my onPageFinished()). Finally the page stucks with no result. Any sort of help regarding how to set timeout period if webView fails to load content is helpful for me. I referred these links but had did not worked:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759978/android-timeout-webview-if-it-takes-longer-than-a-certain-time-to-load)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772409/set-loadurltimeoutvalue-on-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working with this:

```
@Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

        if(webView.getProgress()==100)
        {
            timeout = false;
        }

    }
```

Referred from this link:
[Android WebView TimeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302912/android-webview-timeout/31537328#31537328)